# Connecting 2 socket clients by the server

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'd like to know how possible is it to connect two clients (each one connected to my server), to each other.

S means Server and C Client.
Currently, I have this: [S] <=> [C 1] and [S] <=> [C 2]
I'm looking for to add a new "connection": [C 1] <=> [C 2]

I want to make the connection up even my server shutdown.

Can some one help me ?

Comment: what are you stuck on? Have the server communicate to each client what the IP:port of the other client is, then they can establish a connection using that.

Answer (score 1):

One of the clients must create a server socket and the other must connect to it.

The model would be:

```
[C 1 - Socket 1 (client)] -> [S - Socket (server)]
[C 2 - Socket 1 (client)] -> [S - Socket (server)]

[C 1 - Socket 2 (client)] -> [C 2 - Socket 2 (server)]
```

Comment: Okay, it was what I was expecting, but how ? I mean if one client have a firewall or something, you can't make it as a "server" event if you have the IP address of each one.

Comment: You can see at how to use UPnP in order to tell your box to open specific port without having to manually open them.

Particularly, P2P applications use this to connect to each other: http://superuser.com/questions/333988/why-dont-p2p-connections-need-open-ports :)

Comment: @RaphyTheGeek Enabling UPnP is generally not great for security and using it would make his code virtually unportable. Look into [Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) for a better solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't care about portability :) It will only be executed in a specific Unix distribution. I'll have a look on these methods !